# VisualStudio, focus on the texttip popup

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I was used to the Eclipse IDE that when you hover the mouse on any place in the code it shows a text over the editor (in a popup window) with things like the Error of the line, the documentation of the variable and etc..

Now on VisualStudio the same function exists and I'm able to use the texttip to check the objects docs and etc.. my question is:

How can I focus the popup window so I can copy the text from the tip?

PS: On Eclipse that used to be the F2 (or F3, not sure) key.

Comment: did you end up figuring this out Marcos?

Comment: As far I researched and asked for VS users, this is not available.